# Dovecot doesn't find mailboxes containing plus sign

Tags: postfix, dovecot, mailbox

I'm running a Postfix/Dovecot setup and some of my users use `+` signs in their addresses (**not** using the postfix `recipient_delimiter`).
It's not possible to send emails to them, because the mailboxes are not known:

```
postfix/pipe[15853]: 6C4B4110F01: to=<plussignemailaddress>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.02, delays=0/0/0/0.01, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (user unknown)
```

dovecot seems to be the problem:

```
> doveadm user plussignemailaddress  
> userdb lookup: user plussignemailaddress doesn't exist
```

The mailbox does exist, though. How do I fix this?

The recipient delimiter isn't active:

```
#recipient_delimiter = +
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dovecot - plus sign in mailbox name](https://serverfault.com/questions/748182/dovecot-plus-sign-in-mailbox-name)

Comment: No, the ``recipient_delimiter`` is commented out in Postfix.

Comment: Do you have your accounts in format `+text@domain.tld`? If yes, please read RFC about mails.

Comment: Some users use this format, yes. RFC states that the plus sign is valid as an address.

Comment: Right, but AFAIK not on the begin of the username

Comment: I get your point, the plus isn't the lead character on the problematic mailboxes, though.